# How to publish Visual Studio ASP.NET 5 projects to Docker Hub?

Tags: asp.net, docker

I'm looking for a way to publish my website to DaoCloud, a Docker container service provider.

The provider doesn't open their API for you. They just let you build your APP from source on GitHub or pulling image from Docker Hub. If you're building from GitHub, you can specify the Dockerfile which should be used for building.

But as you can see the Dockerfile in a ASP.NET 5 project 
[image: Dockerfile.release]

It doesn't specify any ports. Neither does projects.json/commands/web. I have tried to add ports specification manually and then build it, but with no success. All contents in the wwwroot folder return 404 error.

How can I create a buildable repository or create a Docker Hub image by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Dockerfile** seems to be right. Here is the one I used to build:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]
```

Maybe you could share your **project.json**. Here is the command into the project.json that matches the entrypoint declared in the dockerfile.

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://*:5004"
},
```

The **(*)** allows kestrel for listening requests from all domains.

You can find some samples here: [AspNet Home Samples](https://github.com/emyann/Home/blob/dev/samples)

Hope this helps !